# How to handle submodules with Maven JGit Flow?

Tags: maven, jgitflow-maven-plugin

I am new to using the `jgitflow-maven-plugin`. My project has many different modules that depend on each other. On my `develop` branch all the submodules have version 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.

Executing the `release-start` goal fails because of the snapshot dependencies. I found that I can use the `allowSnapshots=true` option to get past this, but I'm not sure if this is the correct way of dealing with it.

What is the correct way of working with jgitflow and submodules?

Answer (score 3):

Is

```
<configuration>
    <!-- Keep your maven submodules at the same version as the parent POM -->
    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
    ...
</configuration>
```

from http://george-stathis.com/2013/11/09/painless-maven-project-releases-with-maven-gitflow-plugin/

Answer (score 2):

As of right now, allowSnapshots=true is required to build a project with submodules that duplicate the parent's (SNAPSHOT) version.  Your usage is correct.